# Tuples - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have been given a whole stack of data (900 tuples to be exact) within each of these tuples there are 12 elements stored.

I need to load the second element in the tuple.

How would I extract the second element from every all of the 900 tuples? Any help or suggestions how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Here you go, read this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Answer (score 5):

```
t1 = (something here)
t2 = (something here)
.
.
.
t900= (something here)
l = [t1, t2 ,... ,t900]
a = [i[1] for i in l]
print a
```

Comment: @newprogrammer1001 check the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Tell me if it works.

```
...
yourTuples = [(....), (.....)]
result = []
for item in yourTuples:
    result.append(item[1])

print result
```

Comment: Thanks , yeah that is what i was trying to do it seems to work :)

Comment: a list comprehension is likely to be more efficient - it would be interesting to see the timing differences between using zip, map, list comprehensions and explicit for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Map over the list:

```
list_of_tuples = [(..., ...), (..., ...), ...]
second_elements = map(lambda x: x[1], list_of_tuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using a python package [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)

see the sample code below,

```
import numpy

initial_list = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), ]

array = numpy.array(initial_list)
print array[:,1]
```

Comment: This assumes that NumPy can find a single `dtype` that suits all the tuple elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have stack of data in list form, you can simply do this using `zip`:

```
lt=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
print zip(*lt)[1]
```

output:

```
(2, 5, 8)
```